# Subquery Using Magento's DB Functions

Tags: sql

I am trying to do a query of the form:

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableB.id 

FROM TableA

INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.a_id = TableA.id 

WHERE

TableB.field1 = ( SELECT TableB.field1 FROM TableB WHERE TableB.a_id=TableA.id ORDER BY TableB.created_at DESC LIMIT 1 )

GROUP BY TableA.id, TableB.field1 ORDER BY TableA.id ASC
```

the important thing being that the where clause has a subquery.

My question is, how would you use addFieldToFilter() or even ZendDB functions to implement the subquery?

Answer (score 4):

You would use `Zend_Db_Expr` - which can take either another collection object, an explicit SQL statement, or a fragment of a statement. :

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('TableB.field1 = (?)', new Zend_Db_Expr($subquery->__toString());
```

Here, `$subquery` is another collection but could easily just be the text as you stated, `SELECT TableB.field1 FROM TableB WHERE TableB.a_id=TableA.id ORDER BY TableB.created_at DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Does this break later attempts to use addFieldToFilter?

Comment: Not in my experience, no. In core they do these calls successively -- I've seen `Zend_Db_Expr` used in column definition, e.g. in the SELECT part of the query.

Comment: It's tough to show some really great examples because they're in Enterprise Edition...

Answer (score 2):

You can check this example in the magento source code:
Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Bestsellers::aggregate

search for 'subSelect':
http://www.magentodocs.org/1.7.0.2/d1/d51/_sales_2_model_2_resource_2_report_2_bestsellers_8php_source.php

More examples you can find in the Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_* classes.